# How long should you cook lamb steaks?

Tags: meat

I saw some posts about lamb. but they were related to lamb leg steaks, etc.

Any way, how long should i grill these lamb steaks?

I want them to be a medium? Or should they be served rare (i'm not sure how they're typically served in restaurants) ?

They're about 1/2" thick and they're  (two) both about 0.7 lbs each.

Comment: Lamb is medium at 55°C, and you can eat it rarer than that if you want to. I have no idea about the time your steaks will need to reach it, I roast my meat by the thermometer, not by the clock. Read this article about good lamb: http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/04/the-food-lab-perfect-rack-of-lamb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they usually make them medium at the restaurants, but you could get rare if you like.

Anyway, with a .7 pound lamb, you could probably warm the oven up at 120C for 10 minutes, then put in the lamb, and turn the thermometer up to 180C for round about half an hour, and it should done to a turn.

Leastways, that's what I did.

Comment: FWIW in France you get odd looks when you order your lamb medium. Don’t try it. In fact, once the cook flat-out ignored my request and got served a rare chop (“rosé”) with apologies from the waiter. I was grateful afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

While lamb's flavor is distinctive from beef, I find that using the internal temperature and cooking durations for beef to work well for lamb.